# Работа цикла foreach, С#

Tags: c#, foreach, c#-faq

Как работает foreach, если я кладу в него не просто коллекцию, а метод, который возвращает коллекцию. Метод не будет выполняться на каждой итерации?

Comment: а почему бы просто не проверить? и нет, функция вызывается один раз

Comment: Хороший вопрос)

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать шаг с заходом при отладке, но в метод не кидает

Comment: @Grundy: Сделайте ж ответ из этого.

Comment: @VladD, Андрей уже расписал хорошо :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Нет, вызов `Foo` будет сделан только один раз. Цикл

```
foreach (var i in Foo())
{
    // тело цикла
}
```

внутри заменяется на вот что:

```
IEnumerable<T> x = Foo();
using (var enumerator = x.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var i = enumerator.Current;
        // тело цикла
    }
}
```

Т. е., как мы видим, метод вызывается однократно.

---

(*Подробное и более точное объяснение в деталях.*)

Конструкция `foreach` -- это синтаксический сахар. При компиляции эта конструкция:

```
foreach (var i in x)
{
    // тело цикла
}
```

Заменяется **примерно** на следующий код:

```
using (var enumerator = x.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var i = enumerator.Current;
        // тело цикла
    }
}
```

При этом `x` -- это экземпляр некоторого объекта, который содержит метод `GetEnumerator()`* или имплементирует интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` (или `IEnumerable`), и может быть задан как в виде переменной, так и в виде выражения.

Если в цикле тип переменной отличается от `T`:

```
IEnumerable<T> x = ...;
foreach (SomeType i in x)
{
    // тело цикла
}
```

То будет добавлено приведение к этому типу. При неудаче будет выброшено исключение:

```
using (var enumerator = x.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var i = (SomeType)enumerator.Current;
        // тело цикла
    }
}
```

(Но в цикле вы не можете изменять переменную цикла `i`.)

---

Конструкция `foreach` работает также и для коллекций, имплементирующих необобщенный `IEnumerable`. При этом код получается несколько другой, поскольку у необобщенного `IEnumerator` отсутствует метод `Dispose()`:

```
var enumerator = x.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var i = enumerator.Current;
    // тело цикла
}
```

Если у переменной цикла явно указан тип (`foreach (SomeType i in Foo())`), то точно так же добавляется приведение типов:

```
    var i = (SomeType)enumerator.Current;
```

При этом тип `i` будет `SomeType`, без указания типа — `object`.

---

Дополнительно советую почитать о том, как работают итераторы и `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>`. (Например, в спецификации языка, раздел 8.8.4.)

---

*При этом возвращаемым типом этого метода должен быть объект, имеющий открытые свойство `Current` и метод с сигнатурой `bool MoveNext()`. Это то, что называют «утиная типизация»: можно не имплементировать интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` или `IEnumerable`, а просто предоставить соответствующие методы.

Comment: `IEnumerable` или все-таки `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @Grundy: А зависит от возвращаемого типа `Foo`.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за замечание, обновил ответ. Подходит и то, и другое, конечно же, просто разворачивается в немного разный код.

Comment: @andreycha, хотя принципиальная разница у них только в том, что в `IEnumerable` - _i_ всегда object, а в generic версии конкретного типа? Кстати, как я понимаю при `foreach( A a in Foo())` будет попытка приведения элемента к `A`, если у элементов коллекции другой тип

Comment: @andreycha: Ещё есть тонкость для случая, когда `Foo` возвращает необобщённый `IEnumerable`, а цикл записан в форме `foreach (T x in Foo())` — добавляется приведение `enumerator.Current` к `T`.

Comment: @Grundy: Опередили :)

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется приведение добавляется _всегда_ когда тип элемента коллекции не совпадает с указанным в блоке. Вроде даже такой вопрос был

Comment: Точно :). Обновлю.

Comment: Ну вот вам ещё до кучи: (1) переменная цикла read-only, (2) `Foo()` не обязательно должна возвращать `IEnumerable` или `IEnumerable<T>`, там при отсутствии интерфейса включается duck typing.

Comment: @andreycha кстати, для foreach не требуется именно IEnumerable/IEnumerator. Там же duck typing - достаточно отдать ему что-то, у чего есть метод `GetEnumerator()`, который вернет что-то, в чем есть метод `MoveNext()` и свойство `Current`

Comment: @VladD опередили на 3 секунды :)

Comment: Похоже, слово "примерно" надо было выделить жирным... :). А вот про duck typing совсем забыл. Раз уж мы тут хотим изложить всю информацию о работе `foreach`, то сделал ответ общим, обновляйте.

Comment: @VladD я бы не сказал, что там duck typing *включается* при отсутствии интерфейса. Он там включен всегда как бы...

Comment: А как в там утиная типизация вообще реализована, где то можно почитать? Интересно же, ибо без интерфейсов легальное такое не реализуется, вроде как.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Например, вот что: http://ideone.com/cyJji9

Comment: @Monk: В спеке, раздел 8.8.4. Лежит у вас на компе где-то в C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хотя: http://ideone.com/j4k43n. Я озадачен. Перечитаю спеку.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ага, там всё наоборот на самом деле. _Сначала_ проводится попытка утиной типизации, а лишь при фэйле ищутся интерфейсы.

Comment: @VladD ну конечно же. Делалось-то все для того, чтобы сделать `List<>.Enumerator` структурой. Если бы сначала проверялся интерфейс - это бы не имело смысла :)