# Зачем новый Stream перекручивать в начало?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, filestream

Читая инструкцию про SHA256 на официальном сайте [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=netframework-4.8), наткнулся на интересный участок кода:

```
public class HashDirectory
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No directory selected.");
            return;
        }

        string directory = args[0];
        if (Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            // Create a DirectoryInfo object representing the specified directory.
           var dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
            // Get the FileInfo objects for every file in the directory.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            // Initialize a SHA256 hash object.
            using (SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                // Compute and print the hash values for each file in directory.
                foreach (FileInfo fInfo in files)
                {
                    try { 
                        // Create a fileStream for the file.
                        FileStream fileStream = fInfo.Open(FileMode.Open);
                        // Be sure it's positioned to the beginning of the stream.
                        fileStream.Position = 0;                                          // ???
                        // Compute the hash of the fileStream.
                        byte[] hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(fileStream);
                        // Write the name and hash value of the file to the console.
                        Console.Write($"{fInfo.Name}: ");
                        PrintByteArray(hashValue);
                        // Close the file.
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"I/O Exception: {e.Message}");
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Access Exception: {e.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The directory specified could not be found.");
        }
    }

    // Display the byte array in a readable format.
    public static void PrintByteArray(byte[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{array[i]:X2}");
            if ((i % 4) == 3) Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Я не понимаю, почему тут рекомендуют прокручивать поток в начало,

```
fileStream.Position = 0;
```

ведь он только что был создан? С ним ведь никаких операций еще не было произведено.

---

Быть может тут предостерегаются того что поток создаётся через объект `FileInfo` (не совсем на прямую), а тот в своею очередь при первом контакте с File Handler на уровне OS как-то мог сместить бегунок?

---

### Обновление

Я попытался вкратце воспроизвести код

```
public class StreamTests
{
    public static void PositionTest()
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\test");
        var files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (var fileInfo in files)
        {
            var fileStream = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open);
            Debug.WriteLine(fileStream.Position);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

и для трех файлов, лежащих по пути `d:\test`, получил:

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0

То есть, позиция потока всегда вначале.

Comment: Я может что-то невнимательно смотрю, но там же цикл. На первый проход не обязательно, а  на последующие - надо обнулять. Смотрели `.Open` - он разве обязуется обнулять позицию?

Comment: Так на каждой итерации `fInfo` это же новый, ни разу не тронутый объект.

Comment: Почему новый? foreach разворачивается в while с enumerator'ом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562075/213987

Comment: @AK, посмотрите внимательно, ответ по ссылке, на каждую итерацию while будет создаваться новый объект. А вопрос, вообще, интересный.

Comment: Попробовал найти в документации, что либо об начальных значениях position. И ни чего не нашел(может плохо искал конечно). Подозреваю раз об этом не написано, автор кода хотел написать код который будет работать всегда.

Answer (score 4):

Все очень просто, когда поток создается из файла его позиция будет равна последнему значению в файле. Если вы начнете его чтение сразу то он пройдет последний байт и завершится, что не очень хорошо, для избежания этого устанавливается позиция 0 и чтение потока начинателя с самого начала.

Comment: Я обновил пост. У меня позиция нового потока всегда в начале, а не в конце как Вы говорите.